# Menu layout issue

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a fancy menu of some sort, but cant seem to get my head around a problem currently facing. Here's a image to illustrate the problem:

[image]

The whole thing is built using a **nav** tag that has a **ul** with **li** children.

Basically the **right box thingy** has to **always stay on the top row, right edge**, and when the windows is shrunken or smaller, this position/behavior has to maintain, and the other regular menu items should collapse on the second row.

The 2 boxes have to maintain a order: the one on the left is the **first li element**, and the one on the right is the **last li element**

Here's what I've tried so far:

-position absolute wont cut it, because it will indeed stay on the right, but it may or may not overlay the other elements(current situation);

-floating it, will probably collapse with the other elements on the next row

-adding a padding right to the nav or ul tag, will work, however, the other menu items will always have a right margin that wont allow them to ever fall under the right boxy thing;

Heres a js fiddle to the problem(shrink the results window): [menu issue](http://jsfiddle.net/CLtCL/)

I'm open to any ideas, even changing the whole markup if that's the solution, or some fancy js if its working. Thank you!

The markup used:

```
<nav class="secondary-navigation main-section">
<ul class="align-left secondary-navigation-list">
    <li class="menu-item-block">

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-block menu-last-item-block">

    </li>
</ul>
```

The css used:

```
a{
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #656565;
   padding: 10px;
   font-size: 1.4em;
   line-height: 50px;
 }
.menu-item-block{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: #656565;
}
.menu-last-item-block{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
}
ul, li {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
}
li{
   float: left;
}
nav.secondary-navigation{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}
nav.secondary-navigation:after{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 5px;
   background: #656565;
}
ul.secondary-navigation-list:after,
ul.secondary-navigation-list:before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 5px;
   height: 100%;
   background: #656565;
}
ul.secondary-navigation-list:before{
   left: 0;
}
ul.secondary-navigation-list:after{
   right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nicely explained, +1

Comment: This may not be the optimal CSS solution but couldn't you just use two menus?

Comment: you can use position:absolute and just add padding-right on the 'ul' in the same width of the box so it won't overlay the text

Comment: @Paulie_D Actually he cannot, if you see how it really works :)

Comment: @fatman, it wont work, or at least I think it will still overlay the text, or the items will have that margin comming from the padding

Comment: @Paulie_D I could probably use 2 menus, or take the whole li boxy things out of that context, but I still dont see a solution this way

Comment: it will not overlay the text (http://jsfiddle.net/CLtCL/10/) but the bottom menu won't be able to get beneath the right square

Comment: @fatman true indeed, but I'm looking for a solution that enables the bottom menu to stay beneath right square;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by a little manipulation on the html and css:

1. change the order of the li so that the 2 special ones are on top

   ```
   <ul class="align-left secondary-navigation-list">
       <li class="menu-item-block">

       </li>
       <li class="menu-item-block menu-last-item-block">

       </li>
       <li>
           <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
       </li>....
   ```
2. Change the css rule for `secondary-navigation-list`

   ```
   .menu-last-item-block{
        float:right;
    }
   ```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CLtCL/12/

Comment: My god that was simple, never crossed my mind :) I think this is the only way of doing this, however if someone else has another idea, by maintaining that order: the first boxy thing and the last boxy thing in the li elements, I would welcome it. Thanks a million @fatman!